# How to make text stay in place regardless of the monitor size?

Tags: html, css

My issue is that when I drag my webpage over from my Macbook 13 inch to my Samsung 24 inch monitor, the text... in this case 'Expertise' changes its position. The text moves up, where as the navigation bar stays in place, adapting successfully to the change of monitor.

I know this is a simple case of design flaw. I mean, I haven't used margins in this webpage. Although I want to be able to have a full screen background that takes up half the top portion of the page, although have the text adapt to the screen size. I'm not talking about making a webpage that works on phones and tablets just yet. Just a webpage that will work on different sized monitors, 13 inch, 25 inch etc... I hope that someone can edit my code so I can see what to do!

I want my website to look good on different sized monitors and am not quite sure what I am doing wrong. I used position: fixed; for the nav bar so that when I scroll down it follows the page, although for the text... 'expertise' I am using top, bottom, right, left etc... to position. I have no idea how to align the text where I want and have it work on different sized monitors. Essentially prevent the text from floating left, up etc... I want the text to resize accordingly, although not fall out of place.

I will post my code below, but would like to thank all of you for your time! I'm sorry if I'm not clear enough with my question as i am not even quite sure what the proper terminology for this is.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Aesthetic Media</title>
    <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,700,500' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="styles.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div class="container">

<div class="header">

<div class="nav">

    <div class="logo">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">AESTHETIC</a></li>
    </ul>
</div> <!--logo-->

   <div class="main-nav">
  <ul>
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
   </div> <!--main-nav-->

</div> <!--nav-->

</div> <!--header-->

<div class="main-wrapper"> <img src="#" class="scale-image"/>

</div> <!--MAIN IMAGE-->

<div class="main-text">
    <h1>We are Aesthetic</h1>
    <h2>A Visual Agency From Niagara</h2>
</div>

<div class="content">

    <div class="text-2">

        <h2>Expertise</h2>

    </div>

</div>

<div class="footer"></div>

</div> <!--container-->
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
* {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
}

.container {

}

.header {
}

.nav .logo {
 position: fixed;
 top: 22px;
 left: 25px;
 z-index: 1;
}

.nav .logo ul {
  overflow: visible;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.nav .logo ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.nav .logo  li a {
  font-size: 1.8em;
  font-weight: 800;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000000;
  font-family: 'Raleway' , sans-serif, Helvetica, Verdana;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
}

.nav .main-nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 25px;
  right: 10px;
  letter-spacing: .2em;
  z-index: 1;
}

.nav .main-nav ul {
  overflow: visible;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.nav .main-nav li {
  height: 13px;
  padding: 0 17px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.nav .main-nav li:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}

.nav .main-nav li a {
  font-weight: 400;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000000;
  font-family: 'Raleway' , sans-serif, Helvetica, Verdana;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

.nav .main-nav li a:hover {
  background-color: rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.4);
  padding: 3px 10px 3px 13px;
  -moz-transition: all .3s ease;
  -o-transition: all .3s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .3s ease;
  -transition: all .3s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

.main-text {
  margin: auto;
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 230px;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.main-text h1 {
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 1.8em;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: .1em;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFF;
  font-family: 'Raleway' , sans-serif, Helvetica, Verdana;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}

.main-text h2 {
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 1.7em;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: .1em;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFF;
  font-family: 'Raleway' , sans-serif, Helvetica, Verdana;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}

.main-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
}

.scale-image {
  width: 100%;
}

.content {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}

.content .text-2 {

  color: #CCC;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 600px;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.content .text-2 h2 {
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 1.7em;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: .1em;
  text-align: center;
  color: #000000;
  font-family: 'Raleway' , sans-serif, Helvetica, Verdana;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
```

I'll also link to codepen so you can see what i'm talking about in regards to the 'expertise' text moving all around.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zxVbwb

Thank you!

Comment: What about using percentages instead of fixed pixels?

Comment: Is there any webpages you can send me to? I want to have an image as a background separate from all the content and have that take up the whole width of the webpage, so I can't put a width of lets say 1000 in the container of the website without affecting the image. I don't know how to use percentages :/

Comment: You'll need to work with percentages and understand the principles of position relative and absolute! 

If the parent of something has the position Relative, the child can have the position absolute. 
This will allow the child to be placed exactly where you want it to be in accordance to the parent. And again, to position it anywhere you like, use percentages as that will apply the same position for all screen sizes no matter what the resolution is. A link to understand positioning better: http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/
Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much Brian! Best answer I've received in over three days of posting! God bless :)

Comment: To answer your comment, a simplistic answer would be to use width: 100% for the body, and width: 100% for the image. 
Notice that the body is preferably followed by the image in the html structure. Keep it simple when learning! Create fiddles to play around with the basic concepts and then apply them to your website. You can create a fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/ 
On this site, you have boxes for html / css etc. Just place your code in it and click on RUN, and you should see the result. Also possible to click on SAVE and share the link with us so we can help you better.

Comment: No worries, I know how difficult it can be in the beginning. I'm happy I could help you out.

Comment: Hold on Jarek, I'll provide you with some tips and clean your code for you in a fiddle. 
I'll put it in a answer and you can give me the credit for it. Hopefully you'll learn something from it.

Comment: Brian I can't thank you enough. Let me know what I can do in regards to voting you up etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay I didn't change a lot, but just some things that I thought were crucial to give you a jump start on making it responsive (applicable for all / most screen sizes). http://codepen.io/anon/pen/azgMjo

A couple of tips: in your Css you might want to consider starting out with:

```
html{
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
}

body{
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}
```

The code above makes the base of your website instantly responsive for all screen sizes. The trick now is to make everything else in it responsive as well. 
Also try to learn **HTML5** and use it where ever you can as it's coding to the latest standards for web-development. E.g.:

`<div class="nav">...</div>  Becomes  <nav>...</nav>
<div class="footer">...<div>  Becomes  <footer>...</footer>`   etc.

Another things which is advised is to put your jQuery or Javascript scripts (the one you use to link your jQuery / Javascript) right BEFORE the closing tag of the `</body>`.

And to answer your main question: notice how I gave the parent of the text: `position: relative     AND   the text itself    position: absolute;`

And I placed the text with a `top: 30%;`
This places the text 30% from the top of the parent window on all screen sizes! So no matter what what the height of the screen size is, the text is always placed 30% from the top of it's parent.

I could go on, but I think this will help you to get a jump start.

If you find my answer useful, you can give me points for my answer. 
Same applies for comments, if you find the useful, you can hover over the comment and click on the arrow that points up (which also gives me a point).

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you so much Brian! I tried to up-vote your answer although it says I need 15 reputation in order to do that. I clicked the check mark instead. Although I will keep your profile in mind and follow questions you answer so that when I am able to I will up-vote them! Thank you again!

Comment: LOL, thanks a lot! I'd appreciate that a lot. 
I just up-voted all of yours and hope that gives the 15 you need ;)

Good luck with the coding!

Comment: You too Brain! All the best!